# Open pdf file in internal storage using path directory

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an on going project and it's almost done, basically my app needs to return the path name of files (which is already working) and open said file when scanning a QR code with that path. My code can be seen bellow:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private var textResult = mutableStateOf("")

    private val barCodeLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ScanContract()) {
        result ->
        if(result.contents == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else {
            val pdfUri = Uri.parse(result.contents)
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            intent.setDataAndType(pdfUri, "application/pdf")
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // ToDo
            }
              textResult.value = result.contents;
        }
    }

    private fun showCamera(){
        val options = ScanOptions()
        options.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(ScanOptions.QR_CODE)
        options.setPrompt("APONTE PARA O QR CODE")
        options.setCameraId(0)
        options.setBeepEnabled(false)
        options.setOrientationLocked(false)

        barCodeLauncher.launch(options)
    }

    private val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ){
        isGranted ->
        if (isGranted){
            showCamera()
        }
    }

    private val filePickerLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri ->
        if (uri != null) {
            val filePath = uri.toString()
            textResult.value = filePath
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            QRCodeKotlinTheme {
                Scaffold(
                    bottomBar = {
                        BottomAppBar(
                            actions = {},
                            floatingActionButton = {
                                Row(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .fillMaxSize()
                                        .padding(16.dp),
                                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                                ) {
                                    FloatingActionButton(onClick = { checkCameraPermission(this@MainActivity) }) {
                                        Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.qr_scan), contentDescription = "QR CODE")
                                    }
                                    FloatingActionButton(onClick = { openFilePicker() }) {
                                        Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.qr_scan1), contentDescription = "Open File Picker")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                ) { InnerPadding ->
                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .padding(InnerPadding),
                            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                        ){
                            Image(
                                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.qr_scan),
                                modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp),
                                contentDescription = "QR"
                            )
                            ClickableText(
                                text = AnnotatedString(textResult.value),
                                onClick = { offset ->
                                    selectText(offset, textResult.value.length)
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    private fun selectText(start: Int, end: Int) {
        val clipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
        val selectedText = textResult.value.substring(start, end)
        val clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", selectedText)
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Text copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    private fun openFilePicker() {
        filePickerLauncher.launch("*/*")
    }

    private fun checkCameraPermission(context: Context) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
            android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            showCamera()
        }
        else if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Camera Requirida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else{
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, when I scan the QR Code that contains "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADocuments%2F731d4614-f118-4e79-81d9-e0f92155f262.pdf" it won't open, nothing happens. But if i use the function "filePickerLauncher" to pick a pdf file, then when i Scan the same QR code the file opens, am i missing something?

obs: I'm kinda new to android studio.

I even made multiples QR Codes with diferent paths and all of them start to work as soon as I use the "filePickerLauncher" function, but never before. It's not random but I just can't point out what i'm missing.

Comment: "when I scan the QR Code that contains" -- are you referring to the code using `ScanContract`? If so, where is `ScanContract` coming from? I don't recall that being in the Android SDK.

Comment: @CommonsWare correct. It is not in SDK, I had to implement it in the build gradle.

Comment: This implies that you are pulling in some library that supplies `ScanContract`. What library is it?

Comment: @CommonsWare it's com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0 and com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I scan the QR Code that contains "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADocuments%2F731d4614-f118-4e79-81d9-e0f92155f262.pdf" it won't open, nothing happens

I am assuming that you literally mean that the QR code is of the text:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADocuments%2F731d4614-f118-4e79-81d9-e0f92155f262.pdf
```

...like this:

[image: QR code]

If so, then the reason that does not work is because you have no rights to that content. My guess is that you logged that via Logcat from some other code (e.g., `ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()`). [Your right to access content from a `Uri` is very short-lived](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

FWIW, in the real world, I do not know of a scenario in which the QR code would contain a `Uri` like that. More commonly, the QR code would point to an `https` URL.

Comment: That might be it, any clue on how to solve it? The QR code points to a file in the tablet, that's what the "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADocuments%2F731d4614-f118-4e79-81d9-e0f92155f262.pdf" means, how would I be able to open said file?

Comment: @Dariusdacosta: "how would I be able to open said file?" -- get rid of the QR code. Use `ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()` (or, better yet, `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()`).

Comment: But the QR code is kinda the main objective, basically the point is to, when you scan a specific QR code you open a specific file in the tablet

Comment: @Dariusdacosta: What you want is not really supported on modern versions of Android. Apps like yours (and PDF viewers) are not allowed to have access to all of external storage, for privacy and security reasons, without user involvement. If your app were to download the PDF itself, your app would have rights to it and could serve it via `FileProvider`, and you could have a QR code that simply indicates to your app which of the possible files it should view (and download if it has not been downloaded yet).

Comment: @Dariusdacosta: The closest thing you could do that supports your existing flow is to request the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. With that, you could use filesystem paths and `FileProvider` to serve up anything. However, it is unclear how you would distribute the app, as Google is unlikely to permit it.

Comment: is there any tutorial on how to request the manage external storage?

Comment: @Dariusdacosta: I am sure that there are some. FWIW, I cover it in [this section](https://commonsware.com/R/pages/chap-scoped-007.html) of [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/R/pages/chap-scoped-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/R).